# Need jquery.fullpage.js to only work for the top two sections

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having a issue with jQuery.fullpage.js and was wondering if there is an alternative or something I haven't thought of yet.

I want the page scroll to work only on the top two sections and not for any further sections.

This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <meta rel="icon" href="assets/images/favicon.ico">
        <title>Test</title>

        <!-- Custom CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

        <!-- GoogleFonts -->

        <!-- HTML5 shiv and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="fullpage">
             <section id="one">1</section>
             <section id="two">2</section>
        </div>

        <section id="thirdsection">
            <p>It works!</p>
        </section>

        <!-- Imported JavaScript libraries -->
        <script src="js/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.fullpage.js"></script>

        <!-- test Javascript files -->
        <script src="js/test.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

This is my CSS:

```
/* Resets all html */
@import "reset.css";

body {
    background-color: #D3115D;
}

#fullpage {
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#fullpage #one:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: #4A90E2;
}

#fullpage #two:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: #D0021B;
}

#thirdsection {
    height: 2000px;
    background-color: #4A90E2;
}
```

This is my JavaScript:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage();
```

Here is the jquery.fullpage.js file:

```
/*
 *  created by zhangkai on 2016/10/10 
 */
;(function(global,$){
    'use strict';
    var Fullpage = (function(){
        function Fullpage (el,options) {
            this.$el = el;
            this.currIndex = 0;
            this.animating = false;
            this.init();
        }

        var utils = {
            throttle:function(callback,delayTime,maxTime){
                var timer = null;
                var prevTime = 0;

                return function(){
                    var context = this;
                    var argument = arguments;
                    var currTime = Date.now();
                    if(maxTime && currTime - prevTime >= maxTime){
                        prevTime = currTime;
                        callback.apply(context,argument);
                    }else{
                        if(timer) clearTimeout(timer);
                        timer = setTimeout(function(){
                            callback.apply(context,argument);
                        },delayTime);
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        Fullpage.prototype = {
            constructor:Fullpage,
            init:function(){
                this.initHTML();
                this.bindEvent();
            },
            initHTML:function(){
                this.$el.children().css({
                    'height':'100vh',
                    'transition':'all 0.7s',
                    '-webkit-transition':'all 0.7s'
                });
            },
            bindEvent:function(){
                var that = this;
                var targetIndex,x0,y0,xDiff,yDiff,delta;

                $(window).on('wheel DOMMouseScroll',utils.throttle(function(){
                    var e = arguments[0].originalEvent;
                    delta = e.wheelDelta?e.wheelDelta:-e.detail;
                    targetIndex = that.currIndex + (delta>0?-1:1);
                    that.gotoTarget(targetIndex);
                },100));

                this.$el.on('touchstart',function(e){     
                    x0 = e.touches[0].clientX;
                    y0 = e.touches[0].clientY;
                });

                this.$el.on('touchmove',utils.throttle(function(){
                    console.log('move')
                    var e = arguments[0];
                    if (!x0 || !y0) return;
                    xDiff = e.touches[0].clientX - x0;
                    yDiff = e.touches[0].clientY - y0;

                    targetIndex = that.currIndex + (yDiff>0?-1:1);
                    that.gotoTarget(targetIndex);
                },16));
            },
            gotoTarget:function(targetIndex){
                var children = this.$el.children();
                var that = this;
                var translateY;

                if(this.animating || targetIndex<0 || targetIndex>this.$el.children().length-1) return;

                translateY= 'translateY(-'+targetIndex*100+'%)';
                this.animating = true;
                $(children[0]).on('transitionend', function callback() {
                    this.removeEventListener('transitionend', callback);
                    that.animating = false;
                });
                children.css({
                    'transform':translateY,
                    '-webkit-transform':translateY
                }); 

                this.currIndex = targetIndex;
            }
        };

        return Fullpage;
    })();

    $.fn.fullpage = function(options){
        this.each(function(){
            new Fullpage($(this),options);
        });
        return this;
    };
})(this,this.jQuery);
```

Comment: why do you need a library? just use CSS and apply overflow hidden on the elements you don't want to scroll?

Comment: I want the scroll to action to be smooth and not linear. I will try what you have suggested to see if it works.

Comment: Could you send me a quick example

Comment: which top two sections are you referring to ```#fullpage``` and ```#thirdsection``` or the 2 elements inside ```#fullpage```

Comment: The two elements inside `#fullpage` I need to scroll as jquery.fullpage.js and anything outside/below to scroll normally.